# MacBook Pro wildly oscillating CPU frequency under load

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, cpu

I've been struggling a lot lately with keeping a stable CPU frequency under load for my 2.8 gHz 2015 MacBook Pro 15". I've tried numerous methods, including resetting SMC, NVRAM, hardware diagnostics, cleaning out the internals, changing thermal paste, none of which seems to help in the long term. This causes a very stutter-y experience while using the computer. I've noticed that this happens somewhat less frequently when the discrete GPU is not used, but this still happens from time to time.

I've tried booting into BootCamp and checking the CPU status using Intel XTU. It seems like whenever the frequency reaches the top it thermal throttles for a split second, even when temperatures are in check (I'm talking 70 degrees C). I monitored iStat temperature sensor data but it shows nothing outrageous either.

I'm really desperate now, I'll accept any solution, including hardware ones. Please help! [image]

Comment: What does a “stable cpu frequency” get you?  Where is it written that a CPU ‘s utilization pattern must be linear?  A CPU gets utilized when a call is made to it. This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: For example when using OBS I get frame drops when the CPU frequency drops, which is really not ideal if I'm recording something or even streaming. It's also very obvious during daily use when everything stutters.

Comment: I understand that CPU frequencies are supposed to go high and low, but this is under a steady load where I expect it the frequency to be steady. Under normal loads, everything performs as expected.

Comment: How can you be certain that whatever software you are using is, in fact, applying a steady load on the CPU?  “Under normal loads...”. What’s that? What’s normal for you is  completely different for everyone.  Does your “normal load” vs “heavy load” include the same or different software?  What causes it to become a “heavy load.”  In other words, these terms are way to vague to even guess.  You need to look at CPU load along eith individual processes.  This is asking why your car is revving like this without describing how the person is driving.

Comment: I'm pretty certain it's not my software. The problem exists even in Windows. The issue appears for virtual machines, 3d rendering, video rendering and lots of other things

Comment: Well thats the problem.  Just like telling your yourself  “I’m pretty sure it’s not cancer” and NOT getting a detailed and proper diagnosis doesn’t help anyone, especially you.  How do you ***know*** it’s is not your software?  What diags do you have to share?  You’ve provided  no activity monitor info to even look at.  Your description of “stuttering” may be clear to you, but not to those not looking over your shoulder. Also, if you were experiencing real performance issues You would have said “beachballing” or similar term to describe the spinning colored wheel.

Comment: So, with the new info you’ve added, you’ve got high intensity CPU/GPU apps.  Did you size the Mac correctly?  What’s the graphics spec on that particular MBP?  Also, if happening in Windows, it’s a hardware issue, there’s no system setting thats going to fix that other than getting a new machine.  Personally, I think you’ve sized your machine wrong for the workload (type) you want to throw at it.